# Formatting JPanel to Include ArrayList<JComponent> and Split View depending on view mode clicked

Tags: java, image, swing

I'm trying to create this basic photo editing app via java swing. I have my code to work somewhat for when 1 picture is imported; I have 3 views - photo view which displays the photo only, thumbnail view which should display thumbnails of the pictures and split view which should be a combination of photo in BorderLayout.CENTER and thumbnail in BorderLayout.SOUTH. I've put in images and code excerpts as to why this isn't working the way it should. I can't upload any images but hopefully the excerpts provide much detail.

Split View Related Excerpts:

```
    public void changeMode(boolean p, boolean b, boolean s){
        /*
         * Photo View will display a single PhotoComponent2 in a large area. 
         */
        isPhoto = p;
        if (isPhoto){
            //have a child JPanel set as CENTER component of BorderLayout of the JScrollPane (scroll) 
            childPhoto = new JPanel();
            childPhoto.add(displayPhotos.get(getCurrentPhoto()), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            System.out.println("in lc photo view class");
        }

        /*
         * Browser View will hold all the images.
         */
        isBrowse = b;
        if(isBrowse){
            //have a child JPanel set as CENTER component of BorderLayout to hold grid of thumbnails within
            // JScrollPanel (scroll)
            this.removeAll();
            childBrowse = new JPanel();
            tc2 = new ThumbnailComponent(displayPhotos.get(getCurrentPhoto()));
            childBrowse.setLayout(new WrapLayout());
            childBrowse.add(tc2);
//          for(int i = 0; i < displayThumbs.size(); i++){
//              childBrowse.add(displayThumbs.get(i));
//              System.out.println(displayThumbs.get(i));
//          }

            System.out.println("in lc browser view class");
        }

        /*
         * Split View is a combination of Photo and Browser View in that the top half
         * is Photo View and the bottom half is Browser View.
         */
        isSplit = s;
        if(isSplit){
            //have a child JPanel in CENTER to hold PhotoComponent plus a child JPanel in SOUTH to hold thumbnails
            containsAll = new JPanel();
            containsAll.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            containsAll.add(childPhoto, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            containsAll.add(childBrowse, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            System.out.println("in lc split view class");
        }
    }
```

This is basically all of my problems right now. Currently the thumbnails that are being created are based on the current image. If I go to photo view and and change the image being displayed with my forward/backward buttons and then go back to browser view I get the thumbnail of the respective image. However, I want to be able to create thumbnails for all images being imported and then display it. I tried the for loop (which I've commented out) and that didn't help either. The other code associated with this are my main class that creates the JFrame and the buttons,etc., the photoComponent that has my paintComponent method I use in my thumbnails and lightComponent classes.

MyPhotos3:

```
view = new JMenu("View");
        mbar.add(view);
        pv = new JRadioButton("Photo Viewer");
        pv.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ //change status
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                sbar.setText("Status: By clicking this, you'll be able to view your photos one at a time");
                boolean p = true;
                boolean b = false;
                boolean s = false;
                lc.changeMode(p,b,s);
                scroll.add(lc.childPhoto);
                scroll.setViewportView(lc.childPhoto);
                scroll.getViewport().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                scroll.revalidate();
                scroll.repaint();

            }
        });

        b = new JRadioButton("Browser");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ //change status
                sbar.setText("Status: By clicking this, you'll be able to view all your photos as thumbnails");
                boolean p = false;
                boolean b = true;
                boolean s = false;
                lc.changeMode(p,b,s);
                scroll.setViewportView(lc.childBrowse);
                scroll.getViewport().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                scroll.revalidate();
                scroll.repaint();
            }
        });

        sm = new JRadioButton("Split Mode");
        sm.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ //change status
                sbar.setText("Status: By clicking this, you'll be able to view a single photo with a film strip dimensional view");
                boolean p = false;
                boolean b = false;
                boolean s = true;
                lc.changeMode(p,b,s);
                scroll.setViewportView(lc.containsAll);
                scroll.getViewport().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                scroll.revalidate();
                scroll.repaint();
            }
        });
```

PhotoComponent:

```
public PhotoComponent2(boolean f, Image img){
        isFlip = f;
        init = img;
        x = init.getWidth(null);
        y = init.getHeight(null);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension (x,y));
        bi = new BufferedImage(init.getWidth(null),init.getHeight(null),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        newIcon = new ImageIcon(bi);
        img1 = new JLabel("", newIcon, JLabel.CENTER);
        image = img1;
        this.add(img1);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.requestFocus(true);
        //System.out.println("In constructor");
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(init, 0, 0, null);
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        //System.out.println("In paintComponent");
```

Thumbnails:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.JComponent;


public class ThumbnailComponent extends JComponent{
    /**
    * ThumbnailComponent class is a way to create smaller versions of each photo passed in. 
    * 
    * @author Puja Sheth
    * @version 1.0 10/16/2014
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    PhotoComponent2 pc;
    Image img;
    double x;
    double y;
    int newX;
    int newY;

    public ThumbnailComponent(PhotoComponent2 input){
        pc = input;
        img = pc.init;
        x = (img.getWidth(null))/(.5);
        y = (img.getHeight(null))/(.5);
        newX = (int)x;
        newY = (int)y;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension (newX,newY));
//      add(input);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics gCopy = g.create();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)gCopy;
        g2d.scale(.5,.5);
        pc.paintComponent(g2d);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Won't solve your problem, but a few general comments about your code:

```
scroll.add(lc.childPhoto);
scroll.setViewportView(lc.childPhoto);
scroll.revalidate();
scroll.repaint();
```

You should never add a component to a scrollpane. The only line of code you need is:

```
scroll.setViewportView(lc.childPhoto);
```

The scrollpane will automatically revalidate() and repaint() itself when the viewport view is changed.

```
super.paintComponent(g);
g.drawImage(init, 0, 0, null);
this.addMouseListener(this);
this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
```

Never add listener to a component is a painting method. Painting methods are for painting only. A listener has nothing to do with painting. Also, the painting methods are invoked whenever Swing determines the component needs to be repainted so you will be adding multiple listeners to the component.

Comment: Yes I do understand that I shouldn't put listeners within a paintComponent method but I'm also doing this bit where I can "flip" the photo and draw lines, words, etc. and having the listeners in the painting method is the only way I can get that feature to work. However, the advice you gave me about the adding component to jscrollpane was great!! A few less lines of code haha.

Comment: `and having the listeners in the painting method is the only way I can get that feature to work.` NO! That is 100% wrong!!! It is not the way to solve the problem. You just add the listeners in the constructor of your class.